# simulateTransaction and accounts

Tags: web3.js, nft, simulate

I am trying to use `simulateTransaction` passing account to receive the post balance of those accounts but I am only getting the post balance of the main account not token accounts.

I have tried with different options in the config and nothing, I can only get the post balance of the main account (the one holding SOL).

```
const accounts = ['main address', 'token account 1', 'token account 2', 'etc']

const config = {
    sigVerify: true,
    accounts: {
       encoding: 'base64',
       addresses: accounts,
    },
    commitment: 'finalized',
    replaceRecentBlockhash: false
}
await connection.simulateTransaction(tx, config)
```

In the post balance I should receive - 1 of a token account that is holding an NFT because I am delisting one NFT from tensor, but I am only getting SOL post balance.

Answer (score 1):

To get the post token balances, you'll need to parse out the `data` of each account. If you request `jsonParsed` encoding, you'll get back the token account balance already parsed, ie:

```
const response = await connection.simulateTransaction(tx, config);
const newAmount = response.value.accounts[0].data.parsed.tokenAmount.amount;
```

The parsed response will look like the entries in https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettokenaccountsbyowner